# How would you fix this 4 bar mechanism rig problem?

Tags: rigging

I have a 4 bar mechanism to animate a folding product. As you can see, when rotating the driving bar, the mechanism pushes outward instead of inwards (it uses hand force to make it happen), how can I make this with this rig?[image][image][image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: what about using a pole target?

Comment: what about bending it a bit already in Edit mode? Maybe share your file so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just uploaded the file moonbots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender uses the existing bend of the bones to determine how IK should bend.  We can change the direction of bend by rotating Bone.001 about -10 degrees in its X axis, after which the IK will bend the way you want:

[image]

If we change the rotation at a point when the IK is not at full extension, we'll have IK pop-- it needs to actually reach full extension, which is not the rest pose, before changing the direction of rotation.  In real life, structures like this need to have some tolerance in their joints, or else have some flexibility, so that they can rotate through full extension.  You don't have any tolerance in your joints as modelled, but we could create some capability for compression by using a second layer of bones with stretch-to constraints:

[image]

Here, we do the IK for a first pass, then we use a bone to adjust the center position, and stretch to marker bones, so that we can move through full "extension" through compression of the bars.

[image]

Comment: Hello Nathan, 

Thanks for the answer. Just with the first part it might do the trick for the animation I'm working on.

But, could you attach the blender file so I can look at that bone stretch? I'm just so bad at rigging

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, there it is.